# How to get the input and output feature maps of a CNN model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to find the dimensions of an image as it goes through a convolutional neural network at each layer. So for instance, if there is max-pooling or convolution being applied, I’d like to know the shape of the image at that layer, for all layers. I know I can use the `nOut=image+2p-f / s + 1` formula but it would be too tedious and complex given the size of the PyTorch model. Is there a simple way to do this, perhaps a visualization tool/script or something?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `torchinfo` library: https://github.com/TylerYep/torchinfo

Let's take their example:

```py
from torchinfo import summary

model = ConvNet()
batch_size = 16
summary(model, input_size=(batch_size, 1, 28, 28))
```

Here `(1, 28, 28)` is the input's size, which is `(Channel, Width, Height)` of the image respectively.

The library will print:

```
================================================================================================================
Layer (type:depth-idx)          Input Shape          Output Shape         Param #            Mult-Adds
================================================================================================================
SingleInputNet                  --                   --                   --                  --
├─Conv2d: 1-1                   [7, 1, 28, 28]       [7, 10, 24, 24]      260                1,048,320
├─Conv2d: 1-2                   [7, 10, 12, 12]      [7, 20, 8, 8]        5,020              2,248,960
├─Dropout2d: 1-3                [7, 20, 8, 8]        [7, 20, 8, 8]        --                 --
├─Linear: 1-4                   [7, 320]             [7, 50]              16,050             112,350
├─Linear: 1-5                   [7, 50]              [7, 10]              510                3,570
================================================================================================================
Total params: 21,840
Trainable params: 21,840
Non-trainable params: 0
Total mult-adds (M): 3.41
================================================================================================================
Input size (MB): 0.02
Forward/backward pass size (MB): 0.40
Params size (MB): 0.09
Estimated Total Size (MB): 0.51
================================================================================================================
```

I think `7` is wrong in this output though. It should be `16`.

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://deeplearning.neuromatch.io/tutorials/W2D1_ConvnetsAndRecurrentNeuralNetworks/student/W2D1_Tutorial1.html
Its a free tutorial with extensive visual representations of CNNs provided by neuromatch academy.